# Nginx starts but site not loading? Unable to connect

Tags: nginx, centos, php

Just installed nginx and php-fpm on centos 5.10 but I can't get it to work. There is ping to the server IPs but when I try to open the domains... I am not able to connect. When I restart nginx, it says OK (no errors). Error logs are empty. No matter the domains and IPs. There will be several domains on several IPs running custom php script. What did I miss??

Here is my config:

nginx.conf

```
user  myusername;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  2;

        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_types    text/plain text/css
                      application/x-javascript text/xml
                      application/xml application/xml+rss
                      text/javascript;

    server_tokens off;
    include /sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

several of these: sites-enabled/example.com.conf

```
server {
    listen       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
    server_name  example.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/example.com;
        index  index.php;
    }
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           max;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
location ~ /\. {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off; 
    deny all;
}
    error_page  404              /404.php;
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.php
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.php;
    location = /50x.php {
        root   /var/www/html/example.com;
    }

set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;

## chi http_user_agent for mobile / smart phones ##
if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") {
  set $mobile_rewrite perform;
}

if ($http_user_agent ~* "^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-)") {
  set $mobile_rewrite perform;
}

## redirect to m.example.com ##
if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
  rewrite ^ http://m.example.com$request_uri? redirect;
  break;
}

}

server {
    listen       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
    server_name  m.example.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/m.example.com.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/m.example.com.error.log;
    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/example.com/m;
        index  index.php;
    }
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           max;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
location ~ /\. {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off; 
    deny all;
}
    error_page  404              /404.php;
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.php
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.php;
    location = /50x.php {
        root   /var/www/html/example.com/m;
    }
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.m.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://m.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: This is really just an IT thing. You probably don't have the ports forwarded, or you could have some issue with DNS, or something else. This might even be better on another SX site

Comment: DNS is fine, man. I moved sites to apache server. Works there. Reason to want to swtich to nginx is traffic and faster load time. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: what does your FPM-Pool configuration look like?